# How to declare the following using PInvoke method?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, pinvoke

For the simple Messagebox, checking the http://pinvoke.net/, I get the

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern MessageBoxResult MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, string text, string caption, int type);
```

However the compiler reports MessageBoxResult could not be found. If I change MessageBoxResult to int, then it compiles fine. Any hint about this problem?

Comment: Because that method returns an int.

Answer (score 2):

The definition is also given on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/MessageBoxResult.html):

[image]

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Represents possible values returned by the MessageBox function.
 /// </summary>
 public enum MessageBoxResult : uint
 {
     Ok = 1,
     Cancel,
     Abort,
     Retry,
     Ignore,
     Yes,
     No,
     Close,
     Help,
     TryAgain,
     Continue,
     Timeout = 32000
 }
```

But as other mentioned, always check [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the value given by pinvoke.net is valid.

Answer (score 1):

MessageBoxResult is defined here:

```
System.Windows.MessageBoxResult
```

Comment: How do I know where MessageBoxResult is defined?

Comment: Go to View -> Object Browser and type MessageBoxResult at the search box. By the way, this is the best question to do if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
using System.Windows;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the MSDN page for the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see it does return an int, that's the native return type. I suspect pinvoke.net is glossing over that with the `MessageBoxResult`, although their page mentions in two places that the function returns an int (just under messageboxresult it says "uint 0-6" and later in the example they write the function as returning an int). I'd recommend just using an int and handling that (or converting to DialogResult if possible).